# Python code stops in Virtual Machine

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

I am running some python code set-up on a virtual machine provided by google. The issue I am having is that after some while, the python code stops. I have connected to the server from my terminal, and the script works absolutely fine.

However, after some while it just stops and it's not the script. For example, it's a webscraping script so I should be grabbing around 2m results of data. Sometime it stops at 2000 results, other times at 100,000 results.

I do not know why It does this, any help?

Comment: Can you set up your own virtual machine and run your script in that.  This might at least tell you the machine from Google is flawed.

Comment: @John That's not something I am familiar on, what exactly do you mean by setting up my own VM? I have run the python script on VSC and it works fine for me it's just that I would have to leave my PC on over night to finish it so I'd rather use a VM. BTW, I am on an imac

Comment: That's not something I am familiar on, what exactly do you mean by setting up my own VM? ...... You can get an Ubuntu, Debian or other like Linux ISO file, and install it as a virtual machine using the Virtual App (like Virtual Box, VMware or like) that you are using now.

Comment: @John This looks very interesting! I just gave it a quick search so I will give this a go. However, the VM on the google cloud can run overnight, is there a way to run something like the Virtual Box on the cloud?

Comment: You can move a Linux ISO to your cloud server and install in Virtual Box and see.

Comment: @John That works but I am still a beginner - do you know of any specific articles detailing this or tutorials? Or perhaps there is a way to check if anything is still running on my VM as it uses linux? RN I set up the VM for the scraper again, and it stopped at 7000 results. Perhaps it is still running? I created a .py file to read the results and print it, though I doubt this stops working.

Comment: What I have done is set up `tmux` so that I can enter a terminal where I can see the programme running. If it stops then I'll know what the issue is

Comment: Here is a good VBOX tutorial for install Ubuntu as a VM ..... https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-run-ubuntu-desktop-on-a-virtual-machine-using-virtualbox#1-overview

Comment: @john Installed! Thanks for showing me this. I'll look into how to set this up on a cloud server.